# SSL context in mongo:client attribute using spring xml config

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, ssl, spring-data-mongodb

How to add SSL key store and trust store file path and password in mongo:client options using spring xml to connect mongo db on TLS . Also need to know how to add ssl invalid host name allowed in mongo:client attribute in xml. I am using spring data mongo db 2.2.3 .

Answer (score 0):

This is not XML solution, but via Bean.
This is what I did for 2.2.5.RELEASE. Note that for 2.3.0, there is no MongoClientOptions

```
    @Value("classpath:truststore/mongoserver-truststore.p12")
    private Resource trustStore;

    @Value("${ssl.truststore.mongodb.password}")
    private String mongoTrustStorePassword;

    @Bean
    public MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions() throws Exception {
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory
                .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(trustStore.getInputStream(), mongoTrustStorePassword.toCharArray()); 

        trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return MongoClientOptions.builder()
                .sslEnabled(true)
                .sslContext(sslContext)
                .sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true)
                .build();
    }
```